# Using SUM and ISNULL with a WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not getting the expected results from the query below.  I am expecting to get back 5,262 records and I am only getting 4,279.  I know the issue is with the WHERE clause.  When I comment out the WHERE clause, I get the expected number of records, but incorrect quantities because I need to filter on the Type field.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    a.Part,
    SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty,0)) AS Sales_Qty
FROM
    dbo.Parts a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sales b ON b.Part = a.Part
WHERE
    b.Type = 'O'
GROUP BY
    a.Part
ORDER BY
    a.Part
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put a condition on a column from *the table on the right side of a `LEFT JOIN`* (in this case, `b`) in the `WHERE` clause, you will remove all result rows failing the condition instead of setting missing values to `NULL`.

Instead, put it in the `ON` clause;

```
SELECT
    a.Part,
    SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty,0)) AS Sales_Qty
FROM
    dbo.Parts a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sales b ON b.Part = a.Part AND b.Type = 'O'
GROUP BY
    a.Part
ORDER BY
    a.Part
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have placed the filter in the WHERE clause you are basically performing an INNER JOIN which will only return the matching rows in both tables, try moving the filter to the JOIN:

```
SELECT a.Part,
   SUM(ISNULL(b.Qty,0)) AS Sales_Qty
FROM dbo.Parts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sales b 
   ON b.Part = a.Part
   AND b.Type = 'O'
GROUP BY a.Part
ORDER BY a.Part
```